# File location listener in Java - Spring application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a Java - Spring application. I want to set up a feature to listen a file location(Folder) and has to process a file as a file get created in this folder.

My plan is to set up a spring quartz `cron` job which will run in every five minutes and process the files available.

Please suggest me a better approach.

Comment: I think you should consider system level (via bash scripts) solutions. Java+Spring+Quartz may not (in fact is not) be the technologies you are looking for this specific task.

Answer (score 0):

A choice of solution depends on how quickly an appearance of a waited file must be detected.
If it is not urgently and at least 1 minutes would be OK, then your solution using any kind of cron job would be OK too.
If a file should be detected asap, then you must provide a permanent running program, that detects a file in very short intervals. This can be reached by for this task dedicated daemon. If your program has nothing to do during wait time, then it can contain part for the file detection.

Answer (score 0):

If you have moved on to/are on java8, it provides `Watch Service API` that allows us to monitor file and folder locations.

Have a look at [Watch Service API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html)